# No Startup & other sounds in Xubuntu 12.04.3. Otherwise sounds are working,PLs Help

Tags: sound

I just installed Xubuntu 12.04.3 on my Compaq nc6120 laptop. I just moved to Linux from Windows XP and have absolutely **NO** experience with Linux.

Like in Windows XP, I don't hear any startup/system/shut down sounds in Xubuntu, otherwise the speakers work fine. I played videos from YouTube and I can totally hear the sound on my laptop but not the startup sound. I explored everything possible but couldn't find a probable solution.

Someone please help me figure this out or, at least, direct me to the proper forum.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869787) that I use to install system sounds.  Make sure you update and upgrade your Flash plug-in as well as accept the third party mp3 component that was offered at install.  These help your computer work better.

Hope this helps!